# synctex=-1 works on command line but not in tex file

Tags: latex

Seemingly, `synchtex` can be used by command line like so `lualatex -synctex=1 test`
but also within the TEX file as `\synctex=1`.
All seems to work fine but now I tried also with synctex=-1.
Whereas from command line still all works fine, `\synctex=-1` in latex file
seems to have the same effect as `\synctex=1` resulting in a zipped file `test.synctex.gz`.

Is this a bug?